# Can't get NVIDIA drivers to work on Dell Latitude E6520, Unity on Oneiric

Tags: 11.10, unity, nvidia, dell, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

My external monitor works fine when connected to my laptop's dock using a VGA cable.  However, with a DVI cable, I can't seem to pick it up.  Googling led me to install the NVIDIA additional drivers.  After installation, I rebooted as instructed, and then tried to run NVIDIA X-server settings.  I got a message telling me:

"You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig' as root), and restart the X server."

However, after running `sudo nvidia-xconfig' and then "sudo service lightdm restart", my GUI fails to reappear.  After removing the xorg.conf file created by nvidia-xconfig, I can get my laptop display back with "sudo service lightdm start", but I can't seem to actually get the NVIDIA drivers to work with X.

Comment: What version of the NVidia driver did you install?

Comment: Looking on http://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/latitude-e6520/pd, it looks like an Optimus laptop.

Comment: @RobinJ: Not sure how to find out which version - there was one recommended option, and another "post-release-update" one - I tried both.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: My quote says "NVIDIA NVS 4200M 512MB Discrete Graphics", nothing about Optimus - also the Dell link you provide doesn't seem to mention Optimus either.

Comment: @SteveKroon Under the Video section, there are two cards: the intel one and "NVIDIA® NVSTM 4200M (DDR3 512MB) Discrete Graphics with Optimus"

Comment: Thanks, @Lekensteyn.  So, basically, I won't get the NVIDIA drivers to work.  Should I be able to get my external monitor to work over a DVI cable with the usual open-source drivers?

Comment: That depends on the wiring. On my laptop, both the HDMI and VGA connectors are wired to the Intel card. Plug it and you'll see whether it works or not

Comment: There doesn't seem to be HDMI output for my laptop, only DVI and VGA.  The DVI didn't work when I plugged it in, which is why I started down this road.  Is there a place where I can find out if it's not working because of configuration, or because of the wiring?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and problem here. I had it all working fine on 11.04. My upgrade to 11.10 gave me a lot of problems, I could not use my external monitor. So I enabled the Optimus setting in the bios and thus switched back to the Intel card only. My external monitor worked fine now using intel BUT no 3d rendering/compiz  anymore which sucks.

I tried switching back to using the nvidia driver again today (by disabling optimus in the bios) and installing nvidia drivers. Unfortunately it did not work out and I switched back intel..Though I might have broken my installation a bit by my previous fixing attempts..
I do not want to spend much time on it again and continue working

I will try again when 12.04 comes out. They are working on improving the graphics stack.